# How do I display comma when typing two variables at the same time?

Tags: c

I am asked to come up with a code register which its input is followed by:

Please enter the amount to be paid: $8.68 
Loonies required: 8, balance owing $0.68 
Quarters required: 2, balance owing $0.18

The first sentence is completed, but the second isn't, as the comma before the address overlaps with the comma before the word 'balance.'
Is there any way to display comma just as above, and maintain the comma for the address?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int n_loonies;
    int n_quarters;
    float remaining;
    double amount;
    amount = 8.68;
    n_loonies = amount / 1;
    remaining_loonies = amount -(n_loonies * 1);
    n_quarters = amount / 0.25;
    remaining_quarters = amount - (n_quarters * 25);

    printf("Please enter the amount to be paid:$");
    scanf("%lf", &amount);
    // printf("loonies required: n_loonies");
    // scanf("%d", &n_loonies);
    printf("Loonies required:%d,n_loonies, balance owing $%d\n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your code even compiles?

Comment: Do you want `n_quarters * 0.25`?  `n_quarters * 25` appears errant.  Is this true code?

Comment: What you want? Not clear yet.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.  Then you'll see that you are missing numeric arguments to the last printf.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your print statement is a bit off. It doesn't look like that code would compile, here is an example of how to use print:

```
int x = 10;
printf("x: %d, x address: %p\n", x, (int *)&x);
```

Comment: This is passing a pointer where an integer argument is required.  The result is undefined, particularly on platforms where integers and pointers are different sizes.  You need to explicitly cast the pointer to an integer of the appropriate size, and use a matching format specifier.

Comment: The `void *` cast does not correct this.  It's still a pointer type and has all of the problems I mentioned.  One more time:  You to cast the pointer to an *integer* type.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code

1) Undeclared variables, e.g. remaining_loonies

2) The `scanf` is placed after all the calculations so the user input is just ignored

3) The `printf` is called incorrectly

`printf` needs a format string and after the format string comes the variables you want to print. All separated by commas.

In the format string the variables are given as `%` followed by a letter that tells the type of the variable to print, e.g. `%d` for a signed integer variable, `%u` for an unsigned integer variable, `%f` for a float variable and some more...

So to print a single integer do

```
int my_quaters = 5;

           format string
       |------------------|
printf("I got %d quaters\n", my_quaters);
              ^^             ^^
           Integer type      The variable
```

When the `printf` is executed `%d` will be replaced by the current value of the variable `my_quaters` - so this will print:

> I got 5 quaters

To print two integers do

```
int my_quaters = 5;
int my_pence = 15;
printf("I got %d quaters and %d pence \n", my_quaters, my_pence);
              ^^             ^^            ^^          ^^
           Integer type      Integer type  First var   Second var
```

this will print:

> I got 5 quaters and 15 pence

So in your case it is more like:

```
printf("\nLoonies required:%d, balance owing $%.2f\n", n_loonies, remaining_loonies);
```

**note:** The format string has a lot more options than I can mention here. Read a good book or man page for that.